# i need to display all the original and final price possibles

Tags: python

```
print("Original Price      Final Price")
for originalPrice in range(1,2):
    print(9.99)
    originalPrice = 9.99+9
    finalPrice = originalPrice * 0.75

def finalPrice(originalPrice):
    if originalprice >= 30.00:
        finalPrice == originalPrice  * 0.75 - 5

    elif originalprice >= 50.00:
        finalPrice == originalPrice * 0.75 - 10

print(originalPrice , "    ", finalPrice)
```

how do i make it display the following?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj8Zd.png)

Comment: Provide your expected output in text not as image.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I can't seem to format it right on here, sorry i'm quite new.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function you've written and return the result for it in order to be able to print the value.

Try the following;

```
print("Original Price      Final Price")
for originalPrice in range(1,2):
    print(9.99)
    originalPrice = 9.99+9
    final_price = originalPrice * 0.75

def finalPrice(original_price):
    if original_price >= 30.00:
        final_price = original_price * 0.75 - 5

    elif original_price >= 50.00:
        final_price = original_price * 0.75 - 10

    else:
        final_price = 0
    return final_price

print(originalPrice , "    ", finalPrice(originalPrice))
```

But you have a few issues with the code, instead of assignment you are using comparators (`==` instead of `=`) and you are re-using variables as function names which is causing other issues. You also need to account for the return result when it doesn't meet any condition in your if statements (I've assigned 0 in this case).

Comment: In the finalPrice function the double "=" should be replaced by a simple "=". I think finalPrice should contain a number and not a boolean.